# AllJoyn failed to build base services for ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, compiler-warnings, alljoyn

I am currently at [this link's](https://allseenalliance.org/framework/documentation/develop/building/ios-osx/build-base) second step: Building the Base Services.

When I preform this line:

`xcodebuild -project alljoyn_services_cpp/alljoyn_services_common_cpp.xcodeproj -sdk {PLATFORM} -configuration {VARIANT} ALLJOYN_SDK_ROOT={PATH}`

which I replace to be:

`xcodebuild -project alljoyn_services_cpp/alljoyn_services_common_cpp.xcodeproj -sdk iphoneos -configuration Debug ALLJOYN_SDK_ROOT=/Users/Joe/alljoyn_src/alljoyn`

I get an error that says:

"`The following build commands failed:
    CompileC build/alljoyn_services_common_cpp.build/Debug-iphoneos/alljoyn_services_common_cpp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AsyncTaskQueue.o /Users/Joe/services/base/services_common/cpp/src/AsyncTaskQueue.cc normal armv7 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler`"

and a compiler error that states that it couldn't find some files. I tried [building the core library](https://allseenalliance.org/framework/documentation/develop/building/ios-osx/build-source) using the command line and everything I could think of but nothing works. I think it might have something to do with my folder tree in my root. My current setup is as follows:

```
ROOT/
   alljoyn_src/
      alljoyn/
   openssl_src/
      openssl-xcode/
   services/
      base/
   core/
      alljoyn/
```

I added the core folder because in the setup page their example tree had a folder called core with alljoyn inside.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I deleted everything and started again and it just worked!

I did change one thing though, the `{PATH}` replacement:

`xcodebuild -project alljoyn_services_cpp/alljoyn_services_common_cpp.xcodeproj -sdk iphoneos -configuration Debug ALLJOYN_SDK_ROOT=/Users/Joe/alljoyn_src/alljoyn`

is now:

`xcodebuild -project alljoyn_services_cpp/alljoyn_services_common_cpp.xcodeproj -sdk iphoneos -configuration Debug ALLJOYN_SDK_ROOT=~/alljoyn_src/alljoyn`

I also did not install openSSL this time.

Not sure if these are what fixed it, but I hope so!